# How can I implement 1-1 relation with Grocery CRUD?

Tags: database, relation, grocery-crud

I really need to implement 1-1 relation between two tables. These are my tables:

```
Users: id, username, email, password
Userinfo: id, Isers_id, firstname ,lastname, mobile, address, ...
```

The users table is read only... This is a suggested solution:

```
->set_table('Userinfo')
->columns('users_id','users_id');

->set_relation('users_id','Users','username')
->set_relation('users_id','Users','email')
```

But the problem is that I cannot set two 'users_id' columns!!!
What do you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your example suggest, you only have one relation between the two tables, but want to recover two fields from it.

IMHO the best way would be something like this:

```
->set_table('Userinfo')
->columns('users_id');

->set_relation('users_id','Users','{username} - [{email}]')
```

See documentation and more examples in http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation.

Comment: If my answer solves your question, please mark it as accepted. This way, other users will see the question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Grocery CRUD is awesome, but it does not handle 1-1 relationships by default.

Check out the post in their forum for a possible solution
https://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/3535-implementing-1-1-relation/

Specifically:

> I had this issue before, i solved it using views, and replacing the add, edit, read links to the original table controller methods.When using views instead of tables you need to add

`$crud->set_primary_key("your_view_primary_key_of_table")`